# Rhino Mocks: ExpectationViolationException although calls are in expected order

Tags: c#, .net, rhino-mocks

I'm having a problem with Rhino Mocks. My Test method looks like this:

```
        MockRepository mocks = new MockRepository();
        IServiceCalls serviceCallsMock = mocks.StrictMock<IServiceCalls>();
        _controller.ServiceCalls = serviceCallsMock;

        using (mocks.Record())
        {
            serviceCallsMock.GetX(2);
            LastCall.Return(new List<X> { new X{ Id = 1 } });

            serviceCallsMock.SetX(new X{ Id = 2 });
        }

        _controller.Index();

        mocks.Verify(serviceCallsMock);
```

The calls in the _controller.Index() method are in the right order and with the right parameters. But I get the following failure:

```
Rhino.Mocks.Exceptions.ExpectationViolationException
 IServiceCalls.SetX(Namespace.X); Expected #0, Actual #1.
 IServiceCalls.SetX(Namespace.X); Expected #1, Actual #0.
```

Does anyone know, what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why aren't you using Rhino 3.5 AAA Syntax? It is *much* easier to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
serviceCallsMock.SetX(new X{ Id = 2 });
```

The mock is now expecting to be called with exactly this instance of `X`.
You should probably use Argument Constraints. Try something like

```
Is.Matching<X>(delegate(X) x 
  { return x.Id == 2; } )
```

See [Rhino Mocks Quick Reference](http://ayende.com/wiki/GetFile.aspx?File=Rhino%20Mocks%203.3%20Quick%20Reference.pdf&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) for more details.

Comment: Why not just `serviceCallsMock.SetX(Arg<X>.Matches(x => x.Id == 2));` ?

Comment: Thanks all! I now use constraints matching (in the form Stefan proposed) instead of the instance, which works.

Answer (score 0):

First of all - try to use [Rhino Mocks 3.5](http://blog.benhall.me.uk/2008/05/rhino-mocks-35-goodbye-record-and.html) syntax, it's much easier
Secondly you should get into Replay state after you've set your expectations and starting the actual testas follows:

```
using (mocks.Playback())   {   _controller.Index()   }
```

3.5 Syntax should be something like this:

```
    MockRepository mocks = new MockRepository();
    IServiceCalls serviceCallsMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IServiceCalls>();
    _controller.ServiceCalls = serviceCallsMock;
    serviceCallsMock.Expect(x => x.GetX(2)).Return(new List<X> { new X{ Id = 1 } });
    _controller.Index();
    serviceCallsMock.VerifyAllExpectations()
```

Comment: ReplayAll is not required when using the `using (mocks.Record())` syntax

Comment: You do need to move to playback state somehow... Anyway the 3.5 syntax  is much easier and less error prone

Comment: At the end of the using block, it is in playback mode. This is the purpose of the using block.